# Align the components horizontally in the card header of dash bootstrap

Tags: python-3.x, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I want to arrange three components `html.div`, `dbc.Checklist` and `dbc.Button` horizontally in the card header of dash bootstrap.

The following is the current arrangement, with the three elements lined up vertically.

[image]

Is there any way to arrange the entire component or part of it horizontally in the style element of the card header?

Thank you.

here is my source code.

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    dbc.Card(
                        [
                            dbc.CardHeader(
                                [
                                    html.Div("card header"),
                                    dbc.Checklist(
                                        options=[{"label": "edge color", "value": 1},],
                                        value=[1],
                                        id="switches-input",
                                        switch=True,
                                        inline=True,
                                    ),
                                    dbc.Button("button"),
                                ]
                            ),
                            dbc.CardBody(html.Div("card body"))
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
    style={"height": "95vh", "background-color": "grey"},
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `dbc.Row` and `dbc.Col` accordingly in the card header children component to align your components. Here is an example to align your card header components horizontally:

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    dbc.Card(
                        [
                            dbc.CardHeader(
                                [
                                    dbc.Row([
                                        dbc.Col([html.Div("card header"), ]),
                                        dbc.Col([dbc.Checklist(
                                            options=[
                                                {"label": "edge color", "value": 1}, ],
                                            value=[1],
                                            id="switches-input",
                                            switch=True,
                                            inline=True,
                                        ), ]),
                                        dbc.Col([dbc.Button("button"), ]),
                                    ]),
                                ]
                            ),
                            dbc.CardBody(html.Div("card body"))
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
    style={"height": "95vh", "background-color": "grey"},
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```